# .NET TimeZoneInfo wrong about Daylight savings

Tags: .net, timezone, dst

Can anyone help make sense of this.  Microsoft’s TimeZoneInfo class in 3.5 is telling me the following GMT date is not in Daylight savings for the Eastern timezone, but it is.

```
// Get Eastern Timezone
TimeZoneInfo tzEasternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

// Convert to EST 
DateTime easternTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Parse("2009-11-01T05:00:00Z"), tzEasternZone);

// Daylight saving IS in effect on this date, but Microsoft doesn't think so
Boolean isDaylight = easternTime.IsDaylightSavingTime();
```

Here are 2 websites saying it is in daylight savings: 
http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?month=11&day=1&year=2009&hour=5&min=0&sec=0&p1=0&p2=198
http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/tzc.tzc

Comment: what operating system are you testing this on?

Answer (score 6):

See: [TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSaving](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460642.aspx)

> Because the
>   TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime)
>   method can return false for a date and
>   time that is ambiguous (that is, a
>   date and time that can represent
>   either a standard time or a daylight
>   saving time in a particular time
>   zone), the
>   TimeZoneInfo.IsAmbiguousTime(DateTime)
>   method can be paired with the
>   IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime) method
>   to determine whether a time may be a
>   daylight saving time. Because an
>   ambiguous time is one that can be both
>   a daylight saving time and a standard
>   time...

Also you might look at this...

[TimeZoneInfo.GetAmbiguousTimeOffsets Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getambiguoustimeoffsets.aspx)

Returns information about the possible dates and times that an ambiguous date and time can be mapped to.

Comment: I feel so silly thinking the IsDaylightSavingTime() function would tell me if a time was in daylight savings.

Comment: I've been beaten up by this issue as well. What exactly is ambiguous about whether a time is in DST or not? In my case, IsDaylightSavingTime is returning False when it should be True, and IsAmbiguousTime is also False. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356866/asp-net-3-5-difficulty-getting-timezones-current-offset

Answer (score 5):

This will work:

```
TimeZoneInfo tzEasternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(
                                          "Eastern Standard Time");

DateTime utc = DateTime.Parse("2009-11-01T05:00:00Z",
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                              DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);

bool isDaylight = tzEasternZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(utc);
```

The original code had two issues:

- Even though a UTC value was being provided, it was getting converted to local kind in the `Parse` statement.  So ambiguity could be introduced there.
- The `IsDaylightTime` method on the `DateTime` class will assume the local time zone if the kind is local or unspecified.  After calling `ConvertTime`, the result has unspecified kind, so it was checking against the rules of the local time zone, not the eastern time zone.

Answer (score 2):

`TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(DateTime)`

Correctly returns the offset with daylight savings factored in if the specified date is inside the period